# sleep between two function in android java?

Tags: java, android

I Have class to record sound in my android project .
In this class i have 2 function : start() and stop()
and i have a main class I want run it from other activity such : record(second)
and record some time and stop aoutomaticly after those second !
Like this :

```
start();
//sleep(second)
stop();
```

How I can do this ?
this is my code :

```
package com.example.voicerec;

import java.io.IOException;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;

public class VoiceR {

private MediaRecorder myRecorder;
private MediaPlayer   myPlayer;
private String        outputFile = null;



public void Record()
{
    outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/momeni.3gpp";
    myRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    myRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    myRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    myRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    myRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);

}



public void start(View view) {
    try {
        myRecorder.prepare();
        myRecorder.start();
    }
    catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // start:it is called before prepare()
        // prepare: it is called after start() or before setOutputFormat() 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        // prepare() fails
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}



public void stop(View view) {
    try {
        myRecorder.stop();
        myRecorder.release();
        myRecorder = null;

    }
    catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        //  it is called before start()
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (RuntimeException e) {
        // no valid audio/video data has been received
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



public void play(View view) {
    try {
        myPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        myPlayer.setDataSource(outputFile);
        myPlayer.prepare();
        myPlayer.start();

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



public void stopPlay(View view) {
    try {
        if (myPlayer != null) {
            myPlayer.stop();
            myPlayer.release();
            myPlayer = null;

        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a thread that runs start then sleeps for record time then runs stop :

```
    final int time = second * 1000;
    Thread sound = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            start(view);
            try{
                Thread.sleep(time);
            }catch(Exception e){}
            stop();
        }
    });
```

### sound.start();

or you can use CountDownLatch :

```
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    start(view);

    Thread stopping = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                latch.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            stop(view);
        }
    });
    stopping.start();
```

and after the recording process finished:

```
 latch.countDown();
```

Comment: how i can run this thread ? and when i write the code it give a syntax error : on start() and stop() --> The method start(View) in the type main is not applicable for the arguments ()

Comment: at first, you just write `thread_name.start();` in order to run the thread(look at my updated answer), then you write the methods `start(view);` and `stop(view);` by giving them the correct view argument, at last you must make them static methods to run them in threads